# Jumping to Python library sources with epy/emacs

Tags: python, emacs, rope

I am using epy/ropemacs for my python project. "C-c g" (rope-goto-definition) works fine if the target is my source file. But it doesnt jump to third party source files. What I want to be able to do is jump to relevant third party source files.

This might be just a matter of letting rope know what the path the libraries are. I dont know how to do it though. Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution. Edit **.ropeproject/config.py** and add these lines to to **set_prefs** function

*def set_prefs(prefs):

    ...

    **prefs.add('python_path', '<path to your external library>')***

Example:
    *prefs.add('python_path', '/usr/local/google_appengine')*